# Random and Seed, Generates same value?

Tags: c#, random, xna

I'm developing a small XNA GAME,

```
 for (int birdCount = 0; birdCount < 20; birdCount++)
            {
                Bird bird = new Bird();
                bird.AddSpriteSheet(bird.CurrentState, birdSheet);
                BIRDS.Add(bird);
            }
```

The code above runs at Load function, BIRDS is the List where all Bird's are held.

The bird constructor customize the bird randomly. If I run the code breakPoint by breakPoint the random function generates different values, but if i do not stop the code and leave program running all random values become same so that all of birds become same.

How can i solve this problem ?

the code for random and seeds:

```
 private void randomize()
    {
        Random seedRandom = new Random();
        Random random = new Random(seedRandom.Next(100));
        Random random2 = new Random(seedRandom.Next(150));

        this.CurrentFrame = random.Next(0, this.textures[CurrentState].TotalFrameNumber - 1);

        float scaleFactor = (float)random2.Next(50, 150) / 100;
        this.Scale = new Vector2(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);

        // more codes ...

        this.Speed = new Vector2(2f * Scale.X, 0);
        this.Acceleration = Vector2.Zero;
    }
```

Comment: please show the code that you use to generate Random and Seed...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Chances are you are repeatedly creating a new `Random` object in your code - instead create the `Random` object **once only** (i.e. by making it static or passing it as a parameter)

Since the `Random` default constructor uses the current time as initial seed and all instances of `Random` with the same seed create the same sequence of numbers creating new `Random` objects in fast order might produce the same exact sequence of numbers. This sounds like what you are seeing.

Comment: thanks ! static randoms have solved the problem, i've let random and seed created at once so i've got random random birds :)

Comment: @icaptan: Yes you could create a `private static Random random = new Random();` field in your bird class and then always use that in your code - also I do not see the point of your seedRandom, random, random2 variables - you should only need one.

Comment: thanks again BrokenGlass, you helped lot, i've done it immediately.